# iReport designer 4.0.2 not work with "print repeated value" for Sale Order Line

Tags: jasper-reports, report, odoo, openerp-7

I have checked so many reference link from the Internet for implement the jasper report in OpenERP 7.0 but I had not find any things for printed repeated lines for that report.

I want to print the sale order line as repeated value in my sale order report through jasper reporting Tools (iReport 4.0.2).

I have printed the only with single line of Sale order Line in my report.
my question is that how can i print the multiple sale order line using Jasper report Tools.

**Sale Order SO008 :**
[image]

**Printed Sale Order report using Jasper iReport 4.0.2 Tools :**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am putting hear demo with xml file.

if you are using a eclips for do this thing, then you create first adapter of your data file(xml,db,csv,etc...), and the create adapter option in file menu if you already configure japser or ireport.

after then select template for genrate report and select adpter in next level and after then select element or data field from your data source(like xml,csv,etc..).

i am putting hear both xml and jasper report file with code and preview.

**simple_Blue.jrxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.1.1.final using JasperReports Library version 6.1.1  -->
<!-- 2015-09-22T11:03:31 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Simple_Blue" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="535" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="cad2717b-4892-4b9b-b88d-6a498ba5c63d">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="NEW_DATAADAPTER1.xml"/>
    <queryString language="xPath">
        <![CDATA[/root/item]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="id_1" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[@id]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="name_1" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[name]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="price_1" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[price]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="72">
            <frame>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="-20" y="-20" width="595" height="92" backcolor="#006699" uuid="c001d49d-79c2-4348-a3cd-2879583050ee"/>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="20" y="20" width="234" height="43" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="6a037f28-72c8-4a1a-838b-87c3717e514d"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="34" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[TITLE]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="395" y="43" width="180" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="eaf746c8-e90d-4037-8277-294c4097ecca"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                        <font size="14" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Add a description here]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="13"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="21">
            <line>
                <reportElement x="-20" y="20" width="595" height="1" forecolor="#666666" uuid="d5b453e8-1a8b-4177-ab6c-15aa584044f0"/>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="185" height="20" forecolor="#006699" backcolor="#E6E6E6" uuid="a2ea42b0-c324-4c0c-94bb-1441747bfe2d"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[id_1]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="185" y="0" width="185" height="20" forecolor="#006699" backcolor="#E6E6E6" uuid="8d72f4c9-6fd5-4700-9a5e-13434c64558d"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[name_1]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="370" y="0" width="185" height="20" forecolor="#006699" backcolor="#E6E6E6" uuid="66dce252-f290-405f-ac8a-2f11cc065bb3"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[price_1]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="20">
            <line>
                <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="0" y="19" width="555" height="1" uuid="abfcf8b6-867c-46fb-b320-1fb3961e00e2"/>
            </line>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="185" height="20" uuid="b62d2690-c680-42ef-ad61-930ecf0c5512"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{id_1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement x="185" y="0" width="185" height="20" uuid="97605ce2-8f11-4e21-a8f7-d1a7d4a4f3da"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name_1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement x="370" y="0" width="185" height="20" uuid="29b984d4-6fe4-43b4-83d3-54e168fc2c17"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{price_1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <summary>
        <band/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

And xml file is
**temp.xml**

```
<root>

<item id="1">
    <name>House Box</name>
    <price>5000</price>
</item>
<item id="2">
    <name>New Box</name>
    <price>11000</price>
</item>
<item id="3">
    <name>Kepp Box</name>
    <price>9000</price>
</item>
<item id="4">
    <name>Sound Box</name>
    <price>7000</price>
</item>
<item id="5">
    <name>Desh Box</name>
    <price>3000</price>
</item>
<item id="6">
    <name>Cloud Box</name>
    <price>1000</price>
</item>

</root>
```

And sorry i have a image but i am not sharing hear because i don have repution now show i am sharing it by google drive, public link is : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4rHgCCP3rA9SzdFZVBmTkhwTlU